# How to show div in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I created a div which is `display:none` in CSS file..

Now after executing php script, in one condition, I want to show that `div`.
for this, I write this code.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["done"]))
    {
        if($_GET["done"] == 1)
        {?>
            <script>
                $('#upload_success').style('display','block');
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

I used `Jquery` for this. But this code is not working for me.

Please help.

Comment: Change `$('#upload_success').style('display','block');` to  `$('#upload_success').css('display','block');`

Comment: Try to call inside `$(document).ready`

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: By the way, why you don't combine your if statements -> `if(isset($_GET["done"]) && ($_GET["done"] == 1))`

Comment: Make sure that this block is *after* `#upload_success` in the document.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Create your HTML code like this. FYI: You dont want to use JQuery, it wil use you when the browser in disable Javascript.

```
  <?php
                    if(isset($_GET["done"]))
                    {
                        if($_GET["done"] == 1)
                        {?>
                            <div id='upload_success'>
                                Updated successfully....
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery statement should be :

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET["done"]))
    {
       if($_GET["done"] == 1)
       {?>
           <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){     
               $('#upload_success').css('display','block'); 
            });
           </script>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

For more information about [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: what happens if the div is after this statement?

Comment: @madalinivascu: I have update my answer.

Comment: I have checked it in my local machine then I have updated my answer @madalinivascu ..... ;))

Answer (score 0):

Use simple css if jQuery not working.
Try this instead of jQuery function inside php block:

```
<style type="text/css">
#upload_success{
display:block;
}
</style>
```